# rebooting a linux server from python function using subprocess call

Tags: python, linux

I can't get a reboot suprocess call to work from inside a function in python.

Here's the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
def rebootscript():
    print "rebooting system"
    command = "/sbin/reboot"
    subprocess.call(command, shell = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rebootscript
```

if I run the same code from the main code (not in a function) it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *calling* the actual function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rebootscript()
```

The expression `rebootscript` will simply evaluate to the function object *without* calling it. If you do that in the interpreter, you'll see something like:

```
<function rebootscript at 0xffe1b7d4>
```

The parentheses mean that you want to call the function as opposed to just evaluating it, and the difference can be seen in the following transcript:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 28 2014, 01:34:03)
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> def rebootscript():
...     print "Hello"
...

>>> rebootscript
<function rebootscript at 0xffe1bed4>

>>> rebootscript()
Hello

>>> _
```

Comment: Thanks! that simple parenthesis was the problem. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the error, but you probably have a permission issue. If you are getting an error such as:

```
reboot: must be superuser.
1
```

on the interpreter, you need to execute the call as superuser.

When you are running using `python yourcode.py` and it succeeds, your session probably has superuser rights.

Cheers.